# How to send request through SOAP UI with CDATA within CDATA to Java Application?

Tags: java, xml, soapui, cdata

I am getting following exception while parsing XML

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
```

SOAp Request i am sending:

```
<soap:Envelope>
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ver:ReceiveOnlineBatchExternalAttachment>
         <web:username>user</web:username>
         <web:passwd>pass</web:passwd>
         <web:receiversReference>1232323</web:receiversReference>
         <web:sequenceNumber>1</web:sequenceNumber>
         <web:batch>
            <![CDATA[
              <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
              <DataBatch>
                <DataUnits>
                 <DataUnit>
                  <FormTask>
                   <ServiceCode>323015</ServiceCode>
                   <Form>
                    <FormData>
                            <![CDATA[<melding> </melding>]]
                    </FormData>
                   </Form>
                  </FormTask>
               </DataUnit>
             </DataUnits>
           </DataBatch>
         ]]>>
        </web:batch>
      </ver:ReceiveOnlineBatchExternalAttachment>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have done changes to CDATA multiple times but getting same error.
Could anyone suggest how CDATA within CDATA can be handled in this request?

Tried following but failed:

```
         <![CDATA[ <elements> <![CDATA[<melding> </melding>]] <elements> ]]>>
         <![CDATA[ <elements> <![CDATA[<melding> </melding>]]> <elements> ]]>
         <![CDATA[ <elements> &lt;![CDATA[<melding> </melding>]]&gt; <elements> ]]>
```

Comment: have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860754/using-cdata-inside-another-cdata

Comment: @marco: Yes but not able to fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I speculate that your problem is actually being caused by nested `CDATA` content.  Can you try the following:

```
<![CDATA[
    <DataBatch>
      <DataUnits>
         <DataUnit>
          <FormTask>
           <ServiceCode>323015</ServiceCode>
           <Form>
            <FormData>
                    <![CDATA[
                        <melding> </melding>
                    ]]]]><![CDATA[>
            </FormData>
           </Form>
          </FormTask>
       </DataUnit>
     </DataUnits>
   </DataBatch>
 ]]>
```

The gist of the trick here is that when the parser hits the inner nested `<![CDATA[` it will actually ignore it.  Then, when it hits this:

```
]]]]><![CDATA[>
```

the first `]]` will also be ignored, the following `]]>` will be *consumed*, closing the outer CDATA, and then a new CDATA is immediately opened again which should last until the outer closing for that.

**Edit by @fatherazrael:**

Remove the XML tags `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Reference: [Nested CDATA - correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865357/nested-cdata-correctly)

Comment: Same error. <<The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.>>

Comment: I somehow doubt this...are you certain that you used my exact code?  Also, check the link I provided.  I am fairly certain the nested CDATA tags are the culprit here, and you need fix this.

Comment: I double checked but i am doing the same you told.  but getting same error. Do i need to add  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  in second CDATA or something like this?

Comment: No...everything between the first CDATA and the middle `]]]]>` should be getting ignored.

Comment: Take the problem apart.  Remove the inner CDATA tag and see if it works.

Comment: If remove inner cdata it says : Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158160/discussion-between-fatherazrael-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: I think your XML has some other problems then.  But what I said is my answer I believe to also be relevant to you.

Comment: I adjusted spaces like bring all brackets in same line and next and it is saying XML document structures must start and end within the same entity 
<![CDATA[ <melding></melding>]]]]> 
<![CDATA[> 
</FormData>

Comment: Do i need to put <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> everywhere or something like this?

Comment: We need to remove  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  from these XML's and problem is fixed with your solution. Kindly update your answer so that i can mark it as fixed :) :) :)